# Try Catch inside EXPRESSION of foreach

Tags: c#, foreach, try-catch

How to try/catch only Expression of foreach without affecting other code ?

```
DoSomethingCodeA();
foreach (EXPRESSION) {
    DoSomethingCodeB();  
}
DoSomethingCodeC();
```

I do not want to try/catch the stuff inside CodeA(), CodeB() and CodeC(), but only Expression part of foreach statement. For instance, my expression can fail, because it dynamical loads SQL data and sql server connection can break. Also another example is that CodeB() can modify the Collection which is used for foreach Expression and then line in foreach will fail because this is not allowed. Etc, there also other examples of this, why Expression can fail. While calling GetEnumerator, MoveNext accessing Current or when disposing...

So, how to handle properly and easily inside C# to try/catch the stuff inside Expression part of foreach loop ? If there is no syntax for this directly, what is best practice of handling situations like this?

Comment: Uhm are you sure about your code? Because normally you could just put the gathering of the data taht is to be gone through into its own method (in which you have the try / catch block located) which leaves the foreach without any such problematic code inside of it. (without more details about Expression it is hard to say, but normally you have "foreach (MyType myvar in MydataList)" and if MydataList can result in errors then it is adviceable to extract the failable part into its own method and make an appropriate return value there (and use try/catch there)

Comment: I do not want to copy all data from SQL server table to some local in-memory variable and make sure SQL server will not fail since data is already in memory. This code snippet is good situation, and I am trying to figure out best solution for handling situations like this., the problem can be only inside Expression part. Surrounding whole CodeB or whole Code with try/catch is not my situation and not answer on this question.

Comment: To be clear, you appear to be saying that you want to catch eg `SomeSuchException` if thrown by `EXPRESSION` but not if thrown by `DoSomethingCodeB()`. Why?

Comment: Yes, that is what I am asking, because I do not want to try/catch CodeB() (or sometimes I want) but this never mind. I need syntaxt/sollution how to catch Exceptions thrown inside ONLY Expression part.

Comment: @hkusulja I think it would be best if you give an example on how expression looks like and what datatypes (from what you said in the comments it sounds like there is a slight misunderstanding in how c# handles things in the background but without more details I'm not sure if I'm correct there with my assumption on what you mean and how you try to use things or not)

Comment: Evaluate the expression and copy it to list/array. Wrap the whole thing in try/catch?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel that was what I mentioned in the first comment (and what the 2 answers so far are about).hkusuljas answer to that one is the second comment. I'm not sure if there is a misunderstanding by us in how he tries to do the things or if there is a misunderstanding by him in how the foreach and the data-list work in the background.

Comment: I do not want to copy list / array, but I am aware of this solution, I was hopping there is a better way. Wrapping try/catch on whole foreach and code will effect on codeB behavior (if there is exception inside codeB i do NOT want to catch it). For example, lets say error/Exception on foreach program code line is "The collection was modified", and how to catch it then

Comment: @Thomas Simply put: Unclear what he's asking and why he needs it. expression in foreach could throw for several reasons. While calling `GetEnumerator`, `MoveNext` accessing `Current` or when disposing. I'm not sure how he can handle it without materializing the query.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel exactly that is also my problem there. and the reason why I asked him to give us more details on what he uses as "Expression" as else it is really unclear as to what would be needed to achieve the wished for result (or if it is achieveable at all).

Comment: @hkusulja - the question is incomplete because what should happen after such an exception? Normally the results/actions of CodeB and CodeC should become invalid anyway, so this reeks of a very dangerous error handling strategy.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I want to catch this exception and handle it, so where do I write code for this behavior (when the Exception in Expression part of foreach happens) that is the original question from the start.

Answer (score 2):

If you move any functionality in `EXPRESSION` out into a new method, then catching the exception becomes easy:

```
DoSomethingCodeA();
foreach (var x in SomeMethod()) 
{
    DoSomethingCodeB();  
}
DoSomethingCodeC();


private SomeType SomeMethod()
{
    try
    {
        get some piece of data from somewhere
        yield return data
    }
    catch (SomeException)
    {
        handle it
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but SomeMethod should use `yield return` to maintain the lazy evalauation.

Comment: @HenkHolterman, very good point. I've updated the answer to reflect that.

Comment: @DavidArno So, for instance of dynamically querying SQL server table data, I should implement in my own function. Interesting solution. However, again, what if foreach statement/line of code fails/throws some unpredictable exception outside of SomeMethod() and before CodeB() ? Case can be when foreach will fail of wrong return , and var x can not be the next item because of some error ? (While calling GetEnumerator, MoveNext accessing Current) etc. So I do not believe this is whole answer to the question.

Comment: @hkusulja do you want to catch exceptions on the expression (which is what I've provided) or on the foreach iterator? You seem to want to do the latter, which begs the question "why?"

Comment: @DavidArno the thing is that error/exception can happen in this line of code for many reasons (iterator, expression etc.) , if any of this happens, i want to write ma catch {} and handle it. I have many different situations and I am asking for general solving this in C# coding. Leave business application purpose by side please.

Comment: @hkusulja, you are attempting to write thoroughly over-engineered and over-protective code. But, since you seem determined you want that, please see https://gist.github.com/DavidArno/50c523968245e785eb21#file-over-engineered-try-catch for a solution that should exactly match your needs.

Comment: @DavidArno , I want to avoid having try-catch for the block of DoSomethingCodeB(); , so in your example, I must write the "handle" part, I am aware of this code and solution but does not solves my original request, which is not to try-catch code A, code B and code C.., i was asking is there any native solution how to try-catch ONLY expression part...

Comment: @hkusulja, the solution in the gist rethrows all exceptions in `DoSomethingCodeB()`, thus there is effectively no try/catch block for it. Yes there is a way to catch exceptions in just the expression - it's in my answer above. The `var x in` is not part of the expression, it is C# syntactic sugar for using an iterator to iterate over the values in the expression. The only way to catch exceptions in that too is via the gist I provided.

Answer (score 2):

This is a dangerous way of catching exceptions, because it has a lot of edge cases.

I understand it as your desired behaviour is to return several values lazily, and if at some point getting the next value causes an exception, then you want to silence that exception and just stop returning values.

For example, if there is a database with 100 entries, you might have a situation where you retrieve the first 60 entries, perform some operation on those entries (like copying to another database), and after the first 60 entries, the connection drops so that an exception is thrown inside `EXPRESSION`. In this case, what is the desired behaviour? Should `EXPRESSION` just stop yielding values as if no exception happened? Do you want to rollback the changes you made to the first 60 entries?

Unless you have very good reason not to, I would recommend you cache the result on the query, then you run foreach on the results. This ensures either you perform the operation on all the relevant entries, or you don't perform it on any.

Comment: It depends on business logic, and for now I just want to catch it, and then I will decide what's next..., i have many different situations like this.